# Black creatures that cause loss of life when they enter the battlefield?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I'm looking for creatures that cause loss of life when they enter the battlefield, can you recommend any?

So far I've found [Gray Merchant of Asphodel](http://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=373645) and would love to find more like it.

Thanks!

Comment: Technically, Gray Merchant doesn't do any damage; it just causes loss of life.  This matters for things like [Curiosity](http://magiccards.info/isd/en/49.html); does it matter to you?

Comment: sorry, loss of life is more what i'm looking for

Comment: [Blood Artist](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=240178) sounds like a good card in a deck with this theme. 
You might also want to check out [Blood Clock](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=84709) and [Umbilicus](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=8810)

Comment: @AndSoYouCode Nice suggestions. Blood Clock would be great. (this will be a modern deck)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Technically, there appear to be only three black creatures that deal damage when they enter the battlefield, and for color pie reasons they're all black/red: [Anathemancer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Anathemancer), [Hellhole Rats](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Hellhole%20Rats), and [Murderous Redcap](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Murderous%20Redcap).  However, if, as your example indicates, you're also after creatures that cause loss of life (which doesn't count as damage; this matters for things like [Curiosity](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Curiosity)), you also have available:

- "When ~ enters the battlefield, target player/opponent loses X life."
- [Geralf's Messenger](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Geralf%27s%20Messenger)
- [Inquisitor Exarch](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Inquisitor%20Exarch)
- [Laquatus's Champion](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Laquatus%27s%20Champion)
- [Maga, Traitor to Mortals](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Maga%2C%20Traitor%20to%20Mortals)
- [Singe-Mind Ogre](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Singe-Mind%20Ogre)
- [Soul Scourge](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Soul%20Scourge)
- "When ~ enters the battlefield, target opponent loses X life and you gain X life."
- [Bleak Coven Vampires](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Bleak%20Coven%20Vampires)
- [Bloodhunter Bat](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Bloodhunter%20Bat)
- [Dakmor Ghoul](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Dakmor%20Ghoul)
- [Ghost Council of Orzhova](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ghost%20Council%20of%20Orzhova)
- [Highway Robber](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Highway%20Robber)
- [Obzedat, Ghost Council](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Obzedat%2C%20Ghost%20Council)
- "When ~ enters the battlefield, each player/opponent loses X life."
- [Blood-Toll Harpy](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Blood-Toll%20Harpy)
- [Howling Banshee](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Howling%20Banshee)
- [Maggot Carrier](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Maggot%20Carrier)
- [Rathi Fiend](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Rathi%20Fiend)
- [Netherborn Phalanx](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Netherborn%20Phalanx)
- "When ~ enters the battlefield, each opponent loses X life.  You gain life equal to the life lost this way."
- [Gray Merchant of Asphodel](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Gray%20Merchant%20of%20Asphodel)
- [Malakir Bloodwitch](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Malakir%20Bloodwitch)

Answer (score 2):

You can used the Gatherer's Advanced search to find cards. [Gatherer-Black, EtB+Lose+Life](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&color=+@%28+%5bB%5d%29&text=+%5b%22enters%20the%20battlefield%22%5d+%5blose%5d+%5blife%5d) will find you all Black cards that aren't any other color, that contain the words "enters the battlefield", "lose", and "life" in the rules text. The URL contains variables after the '?', and are separated from each other by the '&'.

- action=advanced :  Use the advanced search instead of the basic search.
- color=+@(+[B]) : The cards color is black and no other.
- text=+[%22enters%20the%20battlefield%22]+[lose]+[life] : The cards rules text includes EtB, lose, and life. Certain characters are encoded so they can appear in the URL, like  and .

Comment: Do you really construct these as URLs instead of just using the advanced search form?

Comment: @Neřekli, no. I was just explaining what the parameters that I passed, and therefore the search URL that returns. In general, I use the search form, unless I want to do something strange and the form is making it difficult (I.e. wanting cards with rules text that is ((destroy && creature) ¦¦ (exile && permanent)) is difficult to do from the form.)

Comment: Who's Neřekli? Anyway, I see - just surprised to see an explanation of the URL instead of how to do it with the form.

Comment: Possibly worth noting for advanced users: Gatherer supports regular expression searches. (Although it doesn't seem to support character classes, unfortunately; this is likely due to the URL encoding more than anything else.)